# Artikel für Temperatur: Um/bei 20 Grad Celsius

Tags: article

> (a) Heute liegt die Temperatur **um** 20 Grad Celsius.
>
> (b) Heute liegt die Temperatur **um die** 20 Grad Celsius.
>
> (c) Heute liegt die Temperatur **bei** 20 Grad Celsius.
>
> (d) Heute liegt die Temperatur **bei der** 20 Grad Celsius.

Eine Google-Suche ergibt ungefähr 818.000 Ergebnisse für "um 20 Grad Celsius", 8.010 für "um die 20 Grad Celsius", 17.600 für "bei 20 Grad Celsius" und keine für "bei der 20 Grad Celsius".

Warum wird dann "um die" verwendet, "bei der" aber nicht? Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "um die" und einfach nur "um"?

Comment: Das „die“ ist Plural, nicht Femininum, daher ist „bei der“ ohnehin falsch. (Zumindest meinem Gefühl nach.)

Answer (score 3):

Die Google-Suche könnte leicht verfälscht sein: "um 20 Grad" wird normalerweise für *Veränderungen* benutzt, also eine Phrase, die in einem anderen Kontext auftaucht:

> (a*) Die Temperatur fiel um 20 Grad.

Eigentlich werden vor allem (b) und (c) für die Beschreibung einer Temperatur benutzt:

> (c) Heute liegt die Temperatur bei 20 Grad Celsius.

Gibt einen *genauen Temperaturwert* an. Das würde man sagen, wenn man gerade auf das Thermometer schaut. (Dass Google hierfür ebenfalls so viele Treffer angibt, würde ich darauf zurückführen, dass es auch im selben Kontext wie (a*) auftaucht: "Bei 20 Grad Celsius passiert X.")

> (b) Heute liegt die Temperatur um die 20 Grad Celsius.

Gibt dagegen einen *Temperaturbereich* an, eine typische Formulierung in der Wettervorhersage. Das "die" muss sich auf einen weiteren Begriff beziehen, z. B. die Marke (auf der Temperaturskala), der aber in Verbindung mit "Celsius" nicht mehr genannt wird, da C. diese Skala impliziert.

Das letze Beispiel ist IMHO nur mit einer Umformulierung möglich, um irgendwie das "der" zu rechtfertigen, siehe dazu auch (b):

> (d) Heute liegt die Temperatur bei der 20-Grad-Marke.